# What does `git merge origin` do?

Tags: git

Someone asked me today what `git merge origin` does.

I said: you mean, `git merge origin/branch`?

Them: No, just `git merge origin`.

So I tried it, and I have no idea what it does.

Let's compare to `git pull origin` that attempts to fetch the current branch:

```
$ git pull origin
You asked to pull from the remote 'origin', but did not specify
a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote
for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.
```

Fair, so what about `git merge origin`:

```
$ git merge origin
Auto-merging ...
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 ...
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

huh? What just happened?

```
$ git log -n 2
commit ec0fe8f2fd20064db34f9379d30b841c692cfced (HEAD -> test2)
Merge: 982c831 ec3393e
Author: Me
Date:   Fri Nov 27 11:14:34 2020 +0800

    Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin' into test2

commit 982c83128f7f77fb187fa85c930a6d11bbfde735 (origin/feature/recon, feature/recon)
Author: Me
Date:   Fri Nov 27 10:43:20 2020 +0800

    lint errors
```

? That didn't come from master.

```
$ git branch -vv
  feature/azure-data                81481f5 [origin/feature/azure-data] fix lint errors
  feature/recon                     982c831 [feature/recon] lint errors <--- !!!
  master                            ec3393e [origin/master] Merged in feature/backfill (pull request #42)
  test2                             ec0fe8f Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin' into test2
```

What? Why did `feature/recon` get merged when I ran `git merge origin`?

Ok, so I created test2 out of `feature/recon`, what if I do that on master?

```
$ git checkout master
$ git checkout HEAD~5
$ git switch -c test6
$ git merge origin
...
$ git branch -vv
* test6                             ec3393e Merged in feature/backfill (pull request #42)
```

So... that merged the current parent branch into this branch?

I see some vague hand-wavy answers around that `git merge origin` is equivalent to `git merge origin/HEAD`, but... what does that mean? Is each remote linked to some kind of HEAD ref?

What's going on?

Note: As far as I can tell this isn't a duplicate, because other questions are asking what `git merge remote/branch` does in various combinations. I get it; that's not the question I'm asking here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I see some vague hand-wavy answers around that `git merge origin` is equivalent to `git merge origin/HEAD` ...

They are (usually) correct.

To eliminate the vagueness, consult [the documentation, specifically that for gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).  Note the six-step process for resolving a string to a commit hash ID:

> **<refname>, e.g., *master*, *heads/master*, *refs/heads/master***
>       A symbolic ref name. E.g. **master** typically means the commit object referenced by **refs/heads/master**. ...
> a **<refname>** is disambiguated by taking the first match in the following rules:
>
> 1. If **$GIT_DIR/<refname>** exists, that is what you mean (this is usually useful only for `HEAD`, `FETCH_HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD` and `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`);
>
> ...
>
> 6. otherwise, **refs/remotes/<refname>/HEAD** if it exists.

Now, suppose `origin/HEAD` exists.  This is short for `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`.  Suppose we ask Git to resolve the name `origin`.  Then if steps 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 fail to resolve `origin/HEAD` to a raw hash ID, we reach step 6.  We just said that `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` does exist.  If it can be resolved to a hash ID, this is the hash ID that `git merge` will use.

> Is each remote linked to some kind of HEAD ref?

If `origin/HEAD` exists, it is normally a *symbolic ref*, just like `HEAD` is normally a symbolic ref.  Run `git branch -r` or `git branch -a` to list remote-tracking names, including `origin/HEAD` if it exists.  Note that there is an oddity here, a bit of asymmetry: `git branch` does not list the symbolic ref `HEAD`, but `git branch -r` or `git branch -a` *does* list each remote-tracking symbolic-ref `HEAD`.

The `git clone` command creates the symbolic reference `origin/HEAD` initially, and the `git remote` command can be used to update it, or to delete it if you don't like it.  If you *do* delete it, `git merge origin` won't be able to resolve `origin` to a hash ID and will tell you that `origin` is `not something we can merge`.

Comment: Makes sense, but in my example, why did it merge a different branch, when on 'test2', `git branch -r` shows: `origin/HEAD -> origin/master`

Comment: What hash ID does `git rev-parse origin` print? What was the hash ID that `git merge` merged? These should match. There's no *branch* name involved, but `origin` is a symbolic ref, so there are two *remote-tracking* names involved: `origin/HEAD`, and whatever it links to.

Comment: Mmm... the commit id is `ec3393e7e0206e89b37c82a19410c6789a2ff2dc` which is the commit master is on,  but it still merges the parent branch. I'll update the question with the details.

Comment: (The output you show in your question seems weird, because you created a new name `test6` and ran `git merge`, which apparently made a new commit, but later, your `git branch` output shows `test6` pointing to `ec3393e`. You'd get this sort of thing if you did a *fast-forward*, which is not actually a merge. You get a fast-forward if (a) that's possible and (b) you allow it, and by default, you will allow it.)

Comment: I just ran the exact same commands again; ie. checkout feature branch, go back in time, checkout a new branch, `git merge origin` and I see the same thing as before; it merges from the parent branch? This is strange no?

Comment: If you run `git merge ec3393e7e0206e89b37c82a19410c6789a2ff2dc`, it should do exactly the same thing, except for the text in the default merge message. Note that if `origin/HEAD` refers to `origin/master`, you're getting the same effect as `git merge origin/master`. Don't just use `git log -n 2` to look at what's going on though, as that can be highly misleading: use `git log --graph` (with `--oneline` and/or `--decorate` as useful options here as well) so that you can see the structure of the merge.